# Progress indicator/"Loading string"

Tags: batch-file, loading, batch-processing, progress-indicator

I have a batch script where 'names/date modified' of all files in a particular folder were written on a text file (named 'texttoken.txt') located on `%temp%` folder. After all the file details have written, each file will be robocopied to folders based on their 'date modified'. What I noticed is that when using the script on folders containing loads of files (ie thousands), it looks like the script had stop working at the moment the files were being written (when it was just taking too long).

What I want is for a progress indicator (like a bar or a percentage) showing how much of the 'writing process' was done. Failing that, a status string ('loading...' or 'files being written') that would run as long as the 'writing process'. How would I start with implementing these in batch?

Comment: Can you include your batch file? The problem can be not only on the detail file generation but also in the file list retrieval. It is easier to detect problems and suggest corrections, alternatives or addons to the code if we can see it.

Comment: this is a snippet of my script: [link](http://pastebin.com/m7KAWwUx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the file copy/move is done by robocopy and the output is not hidden, i will assume your code seems to stop when generating the list of files

Adapted from your code

```dos
rem Get a carriage return into a variable
for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "CR=%%a"
set "spinner=/-\|"
(
    for %%A in ("!sourcedir!\*") do (
        <nul >con set /p"=Searching !spinner:~0,1!!CR!"
        set "spinner=!spinner:~1!!spinner:~0,1!"
        echo %%~tA  %%~xA %%~nA
    )
    >con echo Searching files done 
)>>"%temp%\testtoken.txt" 2>nul
```

Or you can first retrieve the number of files in the folder and then show a percent indicator

```dos
for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "CR=%%a"

set "numFiles=0"
for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d "!sourcedir!\*" ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do (
    if %%a gtr !numFiles! set "numFiles=%%a"
)

set "count=0"
set "oldPct=-1"
(
    for %%A in ("!sourcedir!\*") do (
        set /a "count+=1"
        set /a "pct=100*count/numFiles"
        if !pct! gtr !oldPct! (
            set "oldPct=!pct!"
            >con echo Processed: !pct!!CR!%%
        )
        echo %%~tA  %%~xA %%~nA
    )
    >con echo Searching files done
)>>"%temp%\testtoken.txt" 2>nul
```

In both cases, instead of opening/writing/closing the output file for each file being processed, the full loop is enclosed in parenthesis and redirected.

And this is just a comment. While this will keep the user informed of the process being done, this file generation is not needed. You are writing information about the files and later read the same information. You should do all the processing on the first loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just curious what does the `con` command actually do in this script?

Comment: @mindblues, as the full `for` is redirected, if you simply use `echo text`, the text will be sent to the output file, not the console. `>con` is redirecting the output of the `echo` command to the console.